# Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'

Tags: json, json.net

I am trying to add some code but it turns out I cant add these two together, I am new to JSON and coding in general, anyhelp?

```
    "playerStatProgression": [{
        "name": "HalloweenKillerVialRepetitions"
    }, {
        "name": "HalloweenSurvivorVialRepetitions",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "name": "DBD_HalloweenSurvivorToxin"
    }],
    "specialEvent": [{
        "eventId": "Halloween2018",
        "seenCinematics": [0]
    }],
    "versionNumber": 7
}
"playerStatProgression": [{
    "name": "DBD_GoldenCoin",
    "value": 89
}, {
    "name": "DBD_BurntCoin",
    "value": 53
}, {
    "name": "DBD_SummerKillerCoin",
    "value": 71
}, {
    "name": "DBD_SummerSurvivorCoin",
    "value": 112
}], "versionNumber": 7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to wrap your JSON object in curly braces (`{}`) because a JSON file can only contain one object. Also, it seems invalid. Put it through a [validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to figure out the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way:

```
    [
  {
    "playerStatProgression": [
      {
        "name": "HalloweenKillerVialRepetitions"
      },
      {
        "name": "HalloweenSurvivorVialRepetitions",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "DBD_HalloweenSurvivorToxin"
      }
    ],
    "specialEvent": [
      {
        "eventId": "Halloween2018",
        "seenCinematics": [
          0
        ]
      }
    ],
    "versionNumber": 7
  },
  {
    "playerStatProgression": [
      {
        "name": "DBD_GoldenCoin",
        "value": 89
      },
      {
        "name": "DBD_BurntCoin",
        "value": 53
      },
      {
        "name": "DBD_SummerKillerCoin",
        "value": 71
      },
      {
        "name": "DBD_SummerSurvivorCoin",
        "value": 112
      }
    ],
    "versionNumber": 7
  }
]
```